# Pagination support available in DB2 for z/OS but not in DB2/400?

Tags: pagination, db2, db2-400

I'm aware of LIMIT and OFFSET, available in both DB2's but for my requirements I need to use WHERE.

DB2/ZOS 12 supports ...

```
WHERE (WORKDEPT, EDLEVEL, JOB) > ('E11', 12, 'CLERK')
```

but apparently not DB2/400?

Please someone tell me I'm wrong.

References

DB2/ZOS https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/wnew/src/tpc/db2z_12_sqlpagination.html

DB2/400
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/sqlp/rbafymultiplewhere.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 completely different platforms for DB2

- Db2 for z/OS
- Db2 for IBM i
- DB2 for Lunix, Unix, Windows (LUW)

Despite sharing the DB2 name, they are completely separate products with different code bases.

IBM does try to ensure compatibility, but that doesn't mean that every platform has the same capabilities or gets new features at the same time.

So no, Db2 for i doesn't currently support non-equal row-value-expressions in the WHERE.  You'll have to go old school.

```
WHERE 
  (WORKDEPT = 'E11' and EDLEVEL = 12 and JOB > 'CLERK)
  or (WORKDEPT = 'E11' and EDLEVEL > 12) 
  or (WORKDEPT > 'E11')
```

Comment: Oh MAN that's not the answer I was looking for. :-P
Thank you